# Why Can't transferFrom be an onlyOwner function?

Tags: solidity

Not understanding why this can't and shouldn't be an onlyOwner function. If one had access to the contract, they could easily take tokens from anyone's wallet and transfer it to their own correct?

Comment: Are you referring to the ERC20 standard?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because before an address is able to execute `transferFrom` the owner of the tokens has approved that address to move the tokens, so no one but the users that have been approved can do the transferFrom.

The function is:

```
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = balances[from].sub(tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(tokens);
        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
        Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
```

`allowed` is set by `approve` function. Note that if nothing has been approved or if the amount of tokens is bigger than what was approved by the owner, SafeMath library (`.sub`) will throw when this line is reached:

`allowed[from][msg.sender] = allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(tokens);`

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes indeed it does! That "allowed" line is the key there. Thanks!

Comment: Just thought about something. I asked because I have made it so my website can accept my token as payment. When people checkout another smart contract interacts with mine to complete the transaction. I didn't do anything on my end. Couldn't hypothetically someone create a similar contract to interact with mine and steal the tokens?

Comment: I do not understand. You may want to make another question so that you can describe better the situation. Let me know